# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning only when copied outside of scope

Tags: python, pandas

Why does doing df.copy() not give a warning only if done inside the function scope, but errors if used outside of the scope?

#### Example 1 - Gives Warning:

```py
def do_something(df):
    df = df.loc[df['x'].isin([1, 2, 2698])]
    df.loc[:, "y"] = 0
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 4], "y": ["a", "b", "c"]})
do_something(df)
```

#### Example 2 - Does not give warning

```py
def do_something(df):
    df = df.copy()  # <---------------------- This fixes the warning but is not desirable as it creates a copy (which can take a lot of memory)
    df = df.loc[df['x'].isin([1, 2, 2698])]
    df.loc[:, "y"] = 0
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 4], "y": ["a", "b", "c"]})
do_something(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution - change the function to use `df.loc[:] =`  instead of `df =`

```
def do_something(df):
    # df = df.loc[df['x'].isin([1, 2, 2698])] # <------ Replace this with the line below
    df.loc[:] = df.loc[df['x'].isin([1, 2, 2698])]
    #  ^^^^^^ <--- add this
    df.loc[:, "y"] = 0
    return df
```

Comment: Nope, it returns exactly the same thing :).

Comment: One check you can do to prove that they're the same object is to print the object id by doing `id(df)` on line 1 and line 2. If you use `df.loc[:] = ` they will both have the same id (hence they're the same object). If you use `df = ` you will have a different id for the `df` on line 1 and line 2.